# Kendo UI Editor, can not handle oData format

Tags: json, kendo-ui, editor, odata

I've implemented a kendo ui imagebrowser. My read function returns json in odata format (d.results).

```
imageBrowser: {
              messages: {
                        dropFilesHere: "Drop files here"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Id",
                            fields: {
                                name: {field: "Name" },
                                type: { field: "Type" },
                                size: { field: "Size" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: xxx
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET",
                            contentType: "application/json"
                    }
                }
```

Is there way to handle odata format? Because i think imageBrowser not using kendo datasource. So is there way to parse data to simply json format, or set odata type somewhere?

Comment: Did you try the 'parse' method on the schema?